# jQuery dialog hidden behind bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Got a form displaying data. When you click a form field a jQuery dialog opens to edit the value. But the dialog is getting lost behind the table. Not sure how to correct this.

Here is some code.
Table code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

Link opening dialog

```
<td><a href="javascript:void" onclick="OpenDialog('/LabJobs/Create/@id')">Create Lab Job</a></td>
```

Dialog Div

```
<div id="dialog" title="" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function OpenDialog(urlAction) {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                title: "PTP Popup",
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(urlAction);
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }
```

And a screenshot of the issue
[image: Hidden dialog]

Comment: Can you change the form's z-index to some extremly high value to see if it comes on top of the table `z-index: 999`?

Comment: Pretty simple to inspect css for any element in the live html using browser dev tools. Then you can edit z-index in that live page until it clears up. Then update style rules in css file

Comment: ok I will attempt to modify the z-indexes until I can clear it up. I am not a huge design guy so a lot of this CSS stuff is new to me.

Comment: I was able to correct it by setting the z-index on the .ui-dialog class to 1000. Please submit and answer JonH and I will accept it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct it by setting the z-index property on the .ui-dialog class to 1000 in my css files which is loaded after bootstraps. Effectively overwritting it.

```
.ui-dialog {z-index:1000;}
```